# How to create a pie chart from my sql database and MVC(C#)

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

I'm relatively new to `C#`. I am trying to generate a pie chart using a local database I have made, and I'm currently using `MVC` for `C#`. I have searched a few examples but have not found a clear one. Currently my issue is that the "Database.open" statement is not recognized, any links or help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

```
@{ 
    var db =Database.open("PieChart");
    var data = db.Query("SELECT Id, Name,Percentages from PieChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(width: 600, height: 400)
        .AddTitle("Excel Percentages:")
        .DataBindTable(data, "PieChart") 
        .AddSeries("Default",
        xValue:data, xField: "Name", 
        yValues:data, yFields: "Percentage")
        .Write();
}
```

Comment: Are you using EF or `SqlConnection` to connect to the database? Where is the `Database` type coming from?

Comment: You are clearly going against the whole MVC philosophy in this code. Your query shouldn't be inside the View.

Comment: At first I tried a normal sql connection then I went to EF using the model but with no luck. From what I know mvc providers crud functionality such as edit deleted add. Can you please explain a bit more on the view part or direct me to resources I can check on to give me some light on what am doing.